# How do I add a reaction to a message in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot for a friend so that when someone posts an image in a specific channel, the bot will add a reaction. This is my code for it so far:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(client, channel, message):
    channel = 830207256418058330
    pic_ext = ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg']
    if len(message.attachments) > 0: #Checks if there are attachments
        for file in message.attachments:
            for ext in pic_ext:
                if file.filename.endswith(ext):
                    print(f"This message has an Image called: {file.filename}")
                    await message.channel.add_reaction(tu)
                    await message.channel.add_reaction(td)
                    await message.channel.add_reaction(fire)
                    await message.channel.add_reaction(bl)
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
TypeError: on_message() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'channel' and 'message'
```

Comment: `on_message` only takes one argument, `message`, not three.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński, ah so how can I get it to add a reaction to a image in a specific channel?

Comment: title is inconsistent with the post's body, do you want to send a msg or to react to the msg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Łukasz said in the comments, [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message) only takes `message` as an argument. This will solve the `TypeError` in your question.

Using your channel id, from your variable `channel`, you can check whether the channel the message was sent in, [`message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message.channel), is equal to this id. If it is, you add the reaction to the message, via [`message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_reaction#discord.Message.add_reaction).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = 830207256418058330
    pic_ext = ['.jpg','.png','.jpeg']
    if message.channel.id == channel: # if the channel message was sent in matches the given id
        # then your other code here
```